# Data undefined in a library initialisation Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I use dropzone library, when I load the page the item-id attribute is null, but after a click get a new value but in the initialisation remains null. How can I update the value in dropzone initialisation?

```
    $("div#client_documents").dropzone({
        url: '/clients/' + $('#rootwizard').attr('item-id') + '/documentsUpload', // $('#rootwizard').attr('item-id') is null 
        maxFilesize: 20,
        paramName: 'file',

     ...................
```

Comment: It sounds like you're running your code before the DOM is loaded. Put it in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: `item-id` isn't a valid element attribute. You shouldn't make up your own attributes, use `data-item-id`.

Comment: How does the `item-id` attribute get initialized?

Comment: You need to provide more details and probably more code so we can understand what's happening. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div#client_documents").dropzone({
        url: '/clients/' + $('#rootwizard').attr('item-id') + '/documentsUpload', // $('#rootwizard').attr('item-id') is null 
        maxFilesize: 20,
        paramName: 'file',
//the rest of your code

})
```

looks like the dom is simply not ready by the time your code runs, this will make it wait until ready

Comment: It will not work because `$('#rootwizard').attr('item-id')` get a value after a button click and the dropzone library is already initialised on the page load.